# Angular application getting CORS error on trying generate keycloak token

Tags: keycloak, angular15

For generating a token with keycloak, making an HTTP request using HttpClient  with details in the request body but getting the following BAD request error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8180/realms/SlotScheduler/protocol/openid-connect/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4300' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

NOTE:

1. Keycloak 23.0.3 is running in the docker
2. I have set the following parameters for my client
3. Parameters

Root URL -  http://localhost:4300/
Home URL -  http://localhost:4300/
Valid redirect URIs - http://localhost:4300/*
Web origins - http://localhost:4300/ -- I have tried * also
4. When I am requesting from Postman, it's working fine.

I am expecting a response like
{
"access_token": "",
"expires_in": 300,
"refresh_expires_in": 1800,
"refresh_token": "",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"not-before-policy": 0,
"session_state": "",
"scope": "email profile"
}